# Higher order classes in Python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Can anyone explain why the following code doesn't work? I'm trying to make a class decorator to provide new `__repr__` and `__init__` methods, and if I decorate a class with it only the **repr** method seems to get defined. I managed to fix the original problem by making the decorator modify the original class destructively instead of creating a new class (e.g. it defines the new methods and then just uses `cl.__init__ = __init__` to overwrite them). Now I'm just curious why the subclassing-based attempt didn't work.

```
def higherorderclass(cl):
    @functools.wraps(cl)
    class wrapped(cl):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
            print 'in wrapped init'
            super(wrapped, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        def __repr__(self):
            return 'in wrapped repr'
    return wrapped
```

Comment: for starters, `@functools.wraps()` applies to *function decorators* only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that you're using old-style classes. (That is, classes that don't inherit from `object`, another built-in type, or another new-style class.) Special method lookup works differently in old-style classes. Really, you don't want to learn how it works; just use new-style classes instead.

But then you run into the next problem: `functools.wraps` doesn't work on classes in the first place. With new-style classes, you will get some kind of `AttributeError`; with old-style classes, things just silently fail in various ways. And you can't just use `update_wrapper` explicitly either. The problem is that you're trying to replace attributes of the class that aren't writeable, and there's no (direct) way around that.

If you use new-style classes, and don't try to `wraps` them, everything works fine.

Comment: How can you tell the input is old-style?

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything that I should manually change to provide similar introspective behaviour like functools.wraps provides, or is subclassing itself enough?

Comment: @user2357112: I could tell because I happened to know (and I'm not sure why) that otherwise the OP would have gotten the `AttributeError` exception and wouldn't have asked this question. (It would have been better if he'd actually shown us his class, but he got lucky.)

Comment: @MalcolmGooding: Well, you can't replace the docstring after creation, and you can't even copy it during creation unless you build a custom class dict (either by using a metaclass or by calling `type` instead of building a class the normal way) or do something really horribly like creating source to `exec`. But you can set the `__name__` and `__module__`. So, if you plan to do a lot of this, I'd suggest writing a `classwraps` decorator that sets those for you, and not worry about `__doc__`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `@functools.wraps()` decorator, this only applies to *function decorators*. With a newstyle class your decorator fails with:

```
>>> @higherorderclass
... class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print 'in foo init'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in higherorderclass
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: attribute '__doc__' of 'type' objects is not writable
```

Without the `@functools.wraps()` line your decorator works just fine:

```
>>> def higherorderclass(cl):
...     class wrapped(cl):
...         def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
...             print 'in wrapped init'
...             super(wrapped, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
...         def __repr__(self):
...             return 'in wrapped repr'
...     return wrapped
... 
>>> @higherorderclass
... class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print 'in foo init'
... 
>>> Foo()
in wrapped init
in foo init
in wrapped repr
```